If everything merges in the Supreme Lord at the end of each Kalpa, what is the point of moksha?
I was reading Bhagavad Geeta. In Chapter 9, verse 7-8, the following is mentioned:
"At the end of one kalp, all living beings merge into My primordial material energy. At the beginning of the next creation, O son of Kunti, I manifest them again. Presiding over My material energy, I generate these myriad forms again and again, in accordance with the force of their natures."
However, if one attains moksha then he becomes part of Supreme Lord and is free from birth death lifecycle. Also, its mentioned that at the end of each kalpa everything eventually becomes part of God and then manifested again.
Why do we put effort in achieving moksha if the souls who are living in ignorance and don't make effort in achieving moksha or do bhakti of God also ends up becoming part of God at the end of each kalpa?
If at the beginning of each kalpa everything manifests again then what is the point of moksha?

In Hindu philosophy, moksha (liberation) is an ultimate and eternal state, distinct from the temporary dissolution of souls that occurs at the end of each kalpa (cosmic cycle).
The Bhagavad Gita, Chapter 9, Verses 7-8 describes the cosmic cycle:

"At the end of one kalpa, all living beings merge into My primordial material energy. At the beginning of the next creation, I manifest them again, in accordance with the force of their natures."

This verse explains that at the end of a kalpa, souls that have not attained moksha return to prakriti (material energy) temporarily. Upon the next creation, they are re-manifested based on their past karmas. Moksha, however, provides a different outcome:
Mundaka Upanishad (3.2.9):

"He who knows that highest Brahman becomes even Brahman; and in his line, none who knows not the Brahman will be born. He crosses grief and virtue and vice, and being freed from the knot of the heart, becomes immortal."

Here, the Upanishad teaches that those who realize Brahman achieve immortality and liberation from all dualities. Unlike the temporary dissolution of a kalpa, moksha is an irreversible state.
Bhagavad Gita, Chapter 15, Verse 6

"Neither the sun nor the moon, nor fire can illumine that Supreme Abode of Mine. Having gone There, one does not return to this material world again."

Lord Krishna describes the Supreme Abode as a final destination. Upon reaching it, liberated souls do not return to samsara (the cycle of birth and rebirth).
Brahma Sutras (1.1.4)

“But that (viz. that Brahman has Scripture as His sole proof) follows from the concordance (of all scriptural texts with regard to Brahman).”

This sutra emphasizes that the scriptures affirm Brahman as the ultimate reality, and realizing Brahman results in moksha, a goal upheld as the supreme aim of human life.
Why Effort Toward Moksha Matters:
Striving for moksha is essential because it grants a permanent release from the cycle of creation and dissolution. When souls merge into prakriti at the end of a kalpa, they retain karmic impressions, leading them back into rebirth. In contrast, moksha eradicates karma and grants eternal union with Brahman, free from rebirth and unaffected by cosmic cycles.
In conclusion, scriptures advocate for moksha as the highest goal, providing a permanent escape from material existence. Spiritual practices like bhakti, jnana, and meditation are paths to achieve this eternal freedom beyond the temporary merging of kalpa dissolution.
Sources:

https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/15/verse/6
https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/mundaka-upanishad-shankara-bhashya/d/doc145141.html
https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/brahma-sutras-nimbarka/d/doc376145.html


Loved the explanation. It has cleared my doubt. Thank you!
